# Javascript to delete rows from a queue

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, list

I have javascript on my visualforce page that adds a delete button beside each new case added to the queue but cannot get this button to actually delete these items. This is the code I have so far.

APEX CLASS

```
public with sharing class MassAddCaseNotes {


    public Case_Note__c Case_Notes                    {get; set;}
    public List<Case> cases                           {get; private set;}
    public Map<Id, Boolean> selectedCases             {get; set;}
    public Case filterCase                            {get; set;}    
    public String sortField                           {get; set;}
    public boolean direction                          {get; set;}
    public List<Case_Note__c> queue                   {get; set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController allCases  {get; set;}
    public Integer rowToRemove                        {get; set;}


    private final String selectCasesQuery = 'SELECT Id, CaseNumber, RecordType.Name, Contact.Name, Account.Name, Opened_Date__c, ClosedDate, Program_Location_Assignment__c, Referring_Agency__r.Name ' +
                                            'FROM Case ' +
                                            'WHERE Status=\'Open\' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = \'Case\' AND IsActive = true)';

    public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
   {
           queue = new List<case_Note__c>();
           Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c(); 
           filterCase = new Case();
           direction = true;
         //selectCases();
           direction = false;


   }

    public void selectCases() 
    {
        if (sortField == null) sortField = 'CaseNumber';
        String filter = '';
        if (filterCase.RecordTypeId != null) filter += ' AND RecordTypeId = \'' + filterCase.RecordTypeId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.ContactId != null) filter += ' AND ContactId = \'' + filterCase.ContactId + '\'';
        if (filterCase.AccountId != null) filter += ' AND AccountId = \'' + filterCase.AccountId + '\'';

        allCases = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(selectCasesQuery + filter +  ' ORDER BY ' + sortField + (direction ? ' ASC' : ' DESC')));
        allCases.setPageSize(1);
        updateCases();

    }


    public void sortCases() 
    {
        direction = !direction;
        selectCases();

    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {get {return allCases.getHasPrevious();}}
    public Boolean hasNext {get {return allCases.getHasNext();}}

    public void previous() 
    {
        allCases.previous();
        updateCases();
    }

    public void next() 
    {
        allCases.next();
        updateCases();
    }

    private void updateCases() 
    {
        cases = allCases.getRecords();
        selectedCases = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            selectedCases.put(c.Id, false);
        }
    }


public void addtoqueue()
{
integer counter = 0;
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) 
            {

                Case_Note__c items = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Contact_Name__c = filtercase.contactid,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c 
                );

                 for(integer i = 0; i<= queue.size()-1; ++i)
                {
                    if(items == queue[i])
                    {
                         counter+=1;
                    }

                }                                
                    if(counter <= 0)
                    {
                         queue.add(items); 
                                            }
                    if(counter > 0 )
                    {                           
                    Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,''+' You are attempting to add a duplicate case to the queue.'));

                         }
                    }

            }


}



  @RemoteAction
public static void deleteCase(Id caseNoteId) 
{
   delete new Case_Note__c(Id = caseNoteId);
}

public void removelast()
{
queue.remove(queue.size()-1);
}

public void removeall()
{
queue.clear();
}



public void removeDesiredRow() 
{
    if(queue.size()>=rowToRemove&& rowToRemove> 0) 
    {
        queue.remove(rowToRemove-1);
        rowToRemove= null;
    }
   /* if(rowToRemove == 999 || rowToRemove == 9999 || rowToRemove == 99999 || rowToRemove == 999999 || rowToRemove == 9999999)
    {
        queue.clear();
        rowToRemove= null;
    }
    if(queue.size()< rowToRemove && rowToRemove != 999 && rowToRemove != 9999 && rowToRemove != 99999 && rowToRemove != 999999 && rowToRemove != 9999999 || rowToRemove < 1)
    {  
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.error,''+'Please Enter A Valid Row To Delete'));
        rowToRemove= null;
    }*/
}







public PageReference save() 
{       
     addtoqueue();
     return null;
}


public PageReference submitCases()
{
if(queue.size()==0){
Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.info,''+' Your queue is currently empty.'));

}
if(queue.size()>0){
  integer i = 0;
  while(i<queue.size())
  {
     insert queue[i];
     i++;
  }

  queue.clear();


  }
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/MassAddCaseNotes');
  pg.setRedirect(true);
  return pg;
}

/*
public PageReference saveandclose() 
{
        List<Case_Note__c> note = new List<Case_Note__c>();
        for (Case c : cases) 
        {
            if (selectedCases.get(c.Id)) 
            {
                Case_Note__c s = new Case_Note__c(
                    Case__c = c.Id,
                    Date__c = Case_Notes.Date__c,
                    Note__c = Case_Notes.Note__c
                );               

                note.add(s);
            }
        }
        insert note;  

     PageReference pg = new PageReference('/500/o');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
}
*/


}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">







<apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />  
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
<apex:form style="width:450px" > 

    <apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" id="block1">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes " columns="2" id="section1">
            <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]) </script>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote">Notes:  </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px;" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
                <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote">Date:  </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Find Cases" columns="1">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> 
                <apex:outputLabel for="contactFilter">Contact Search: </apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputField value="{!filtercase.contactid}" required="true" id="contactFilter" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!selectCases}"   value="Filter" />                  
            </apex:panelGrid>

            <apex:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">          
               <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!cases}"  var="case"  id="case">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectedCases[case.Id]}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Case Number" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="CaseNumber" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.CaseNumber}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Record Type" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="RecordType.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.RecordType.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Contact" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Contact.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Contact.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Account" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Account.Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Account.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Date Opened" action="{!sortCases}">
                            <apex:param name="productSortField" value="Opened_Date__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!case.Opened_Date__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                           </apex:PageBlockTable> 
                           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save To Case Queue" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form> 


<apex:variable var="rowcount" value="{!1}" />

<apex:form style="width:400px" > 
     <apex:pageBlock title="Case Queue" >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >



          <script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteCaseNote(caseNoteId) {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MassAddCaseNotes.deleteCase}',
            caseNoteId, 

                    // Refresh the page after deleting the record.

                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>






                      <apex:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!submitCases}" value="Submit Notes"  status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSubmitCases" immediate="false" />
                     </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

        <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>
        <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
                <br/>      

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Queue" columns="1">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete Row #: " action="{!removeDesiredRow}"/>
                     <apex:inputText value="{!rowToRemove}" style="width:30px" /> 
                     <apex:commandButton value="Delete all " action="{!removeall}"/>
                    </apex:panelGrid>

                        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!queue}" var="que">
                        <apex:column >
                            <button  onclick="deleteCaseNote()">delete</button>
                        </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Contact Name" value="{!que.Contact_Name__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Case Number" value="{!que.Case__c}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Date" value="{!que.Date__c}"/>
                     </apex:pageblocktable>  



                </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>  


</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript posted is not syntactically correct - check your browser's JavaScript console to see the reported error.

The code should probably be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteCaseNote(caseNoteId) {
    console.log('delete ' + caseNoteId);
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MassAddCaseNotes.deleteCase}',
            caseNoteId,
            function(result, event) {
                console.log('status ' + event.status);
                console.log('type ' + event. type);
                console.log('message ' + event. message);
                console.log('where ' + event. where);
                // Refresh the page after deleting the record
                location.reload();
            });
}
</script>
```

and also the ID is not being passed to the function so this line of the Visualforce needs to change too:

```
<button onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!que.Id}')">delete</button>
```

Comment: I received no JavaScript errors when I ran my initial JavaScript code. I have made the suggested changes and tested it, still no errors and it still does nothing. You said that this needed to be changed: '<button onclick="deleteCaseNote('{!que.Id}')">delete</button>' , did you mean that it needed to be changed from this '<button  onclick="deleteCaseNote()">delete</button>'  to what you have or it is just wrong all together because I changed it to what you have and it is still not wanting to work.

Comment: On the Visualforce change, yes I meant change it to pass in the ID as shown in the answer. I've put a bunch of console.log calls in that might tell you something and suggest you look at the debug log in Salesforce too to see if the method there runs.

Comment: This is the error I am getting. **Visualforce Remoting Exception: Invalid id value for this SObject type:  object.f {statusCode: 400, type: "exception", tid: 2, ref: false, action: "MassAddCaseNotes"…}**

Comment: I see what the problem is in this code. It is trying to delete the case before it has been submitted. These cases are put into a list called queue until I hit the submit case notes button. My goal is to simply delete them out of the list not delete them from the database.